# Exercise 14.5, "Think Python" (Allen Downey)

Tags: python, urllib

I'm a first time programmer, first time StackOverflow user, studying from [Allen Downey's free online text "Think Python"](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/).

The code shown here is from exercise 14.5 (p.143). I've been trying to figure out what that `.fp` does; my searches all came up empty. I ran the code both with and without it and didn't notice any difference in the results. I'd appreciate anyone's help on this.

```
import urllib

conn = urllib.urlopen('http://thinkpython.com/secret.html')

for line in conn.fp:
    print line.strip()
```

Comment: @MaksymPolshcha
@SeanJohnson
@monkut
@KayZhu

A sincere thanks to your replies. It took me a while to digest your answers; I'm still getting accustomed to the lexicon used in Python documentation.

As far as I can understand, the `.fp` is a property inherent in file-like/Request objects, so it does not need to be specified (in this way of usage). It's sort of like specifying `r` to open a file in read mode only, even though it's not necessary as Python opens a file in that mode by default. If this is a reckless comparison, please let me know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's just a faux file object attached to a socket object.

Read the docstring:

```
>>> help(conn.fp)
```

Comment: Ah, it never occurred to me to use Python's built-in help function. Classes are still somewhat foreign territory for me, but when I entered `help(conn)`, the docstring showed `fp` as one of the arguments for the `__init__` constructor. That cleared things up. Thanks for pointing that our for me!

Answer (score 4):

urllib.urlopen returns a [Request](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/urllib.request.html#urllib.request.Request) object, which has .fp (file pointer) as a property. By default, the Request object when iterated over uses the same pointer, so there's no functional difference.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned it's a file pointer, which is not really needed in this example since the object , `conn` returned by `urlopen()` is already a file-like object and you can call `readlines()` on it.

I think it would cause less confusion if the example was changed to:

```
import urllib

conn = urllib.urlopen('http://thinkpython.com/secret.html')

for line in conn.readlines():
    print line.strip()
```

Comment: True, but I prefer to be explicit, especially when explaining to beginners.